# Specify ESLint carry-over behaviour

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor, jsx, eslint

I use Atom with `prettier-eslint` package. So when I save file prettier automatically format it to conform ESLint rules. All developers in my team are also using it. But every time somebody saves the same file I see lines like this during code review.
[image]

It's the same line, but with carry-overs. How can I configure ESLint to set formatting JSX in one-liner manner or in multi-liner?

Comment: I've taken a quick look into ESLint rules, and I didn't find any rule enforcing what you want to achieve.

Comment: We haven't solved this particular problem. But we configured `.prettierrc` and put it under git, so every team member have same config. For me it seems like prettier improve and fixate rules every release. Also see this [issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/2898) in prettier, that was created by our team member.